# Get_the_date doesnt show todays date

Tags: date

I tried the_date, the_time and get_the_date to show todays date on the website. But wordpress takes latest post's date and publishes it. For example on the index page if the latest post was posted on 12 of August despite i placed that code on very top of the page it shows 12of august as date. also when i visit any of the single page it shows that post's date.

i need help on this.. thanks

and if necessary  this is the header code

http://jsfiddle.net/AvMkY/

Answer (score 4):

That's because that's what those functions do.

For example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date

Use the PHP `date()` function

Comment: oh yes that is what i was trying to do. but tried to use WP :) thanks